# How can I make one Image over another in JavaFX and change it again in an ActionTimer?

Tags: java, image, javafx, effects

I want to put the image "earth" which is moving up and down infront of the image "sun", so it creates a 3d-effect.

I already tried using setBlendMode but apparently that doesn't work for images.

This is my code:

```java
theStage.setTitle( "Timeline Example" );

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene theScene = new Scene( root );
        theStage.setScene( theScene );

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas( 512, 512 );
        root.getChildren().add( canvas );

        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        Image earth = new Image( "/experiment/img/earth.png" );
        Image sun   = new Image( "/experiment/img/sun.png" );
        Image space = new Image( "/experiment/img/space.png" );

        final long startNanoTime = System.nanoTime();

        new AnimationTimer()
        {
            public void handle(long currentNanoTime)
            {
                double t = (currentNanoTime - startNanoTime) / 1000000000.0;

                double x = 232;
                double y = 232 + 128 * Math.sin(t);

                // background image clears canvas
                gc.drawImage( space, 0, 0 );
                gc.drawImage( earth, x, y );
                gc.drawImage( sun, 196, 196 );
            }
        }.start();

        theStage.show();
    }
```

How can I make the earth over the sun everytime it goes down?

[earth.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSXn2.png)

[sun.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtR4w.png)

[space.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSGx3.png)

Comment: Manipulating the blend mode shouldn't be necessary. png images support transparency and I hope your images are transparent in every part that doesn't show the planet/star. Drawing the sun after drawing the earth results in the sun covering the earth though. Pretty sure the desired result is the other way round...

Comment: Link the images you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the function toBack() and toFront() which do exactly what they say. They put an ImageView or any other Node in the back/foreground. And I don't use a canvas anymore. I found them thanks to my java teacher.